# PHP new line between image and text

Tags: php, wordpress, image, web, text

I checked a related question and I saw the syntax for a new line is:

```
"\r\n"
```

However, I don't know how to add that to the code of my website:

```
<h2><span>Sneak peak</span></h2>
<ul>
<?php query_posts('orderby=post_date&posts_per_page= 6'); if ( have_posts() ) :  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<li>

<h3 class="short_title"><a title="Post: <?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo ShortTitle(get_the_title()); ?> </a></h3>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php getImage('1'); ?></a>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), '6');
        echo '...</a>';
        echo '</li>'; ?></a>

<?php endwhile; ?></li>
<?php else : ?>
<p>Sorry, no posts were found.</p>
<?php endif; ?>


</ul>
```

[This is my website](http://www.wha2wear.com), and what I want to do is putting the text down the images in "Sneak peak" in a new line.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Use a simple `<br>` after the image or put it inside a `<div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your image:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php getImage('1'); ?></a>
```

And this is the excerpt:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), '6');
    echo '...</a>';
    echo '</li>'; ?></a>
```

In HTML, to make a new line, you write:

```
<br><!-- br is short for "break" -->
```

So to put a new line between the image and text, simply write:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php getImage('1'); ?></a>

<br>

<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), '6');
    echo '...</a>';
    echo '</li>'; ?></a>
```

---

That being said, better practice would be to make your image a `block` styled element with CSS and then it will fill the width, forcing the text onto a new line.

As I'm not clear on what the function `getImage()` does, here would be my solution:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div class="imageContainer">
        <?php getImage("1"); ?>
    </div>
</a>
```

And with CSS:

```
.imageContainer {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

This will keep the dimensions of your image, center it, and then also force the text onto a new line.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! I put the `<br>` as a quick solution for now. The function `getImage()` I think it takes the first picture of the post.

Comment: @Wha2wear If there was a function to only grab the URL of the image, you could make the images look a lot nicer and fill the function too. However, `getImage()` outputs an entire processed output that includes a calculated width and height for the image.

Comment: that's how wordpress suggested to do it so I guess that may be faster to load the images? as wordpress is really slow when loading pages

Answer (score 0):

Simply add

```
#content .blog ul li a + a { display: block; }
```

to your style.css and this will style it as you desire.